# Two Numbers & Printing the List from the First to Second Number

Tags: python, numbers

I need to make a code where the user enters two numbers (for example, 7 and -7) and the code will print a list of numbers between it. `(-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`

I have only got the input so far:

```
number = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
number = int(input('Enter the second number: '))
```

It should look like this:

```
Enter the first number: 7
Enter the second number: -7

(-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: are you looking for range ?

Comment: What have you tried to do to print the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `range`:

```
number = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
number2 = int(input('Enter the second number: '))
print(list(range(number2, number + 1)))
```

Example output:

```
Enter the first number: 7
Enter the second number: -7
[-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

If you want a `tuple`:

```
number = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
number2 = int(input('Enter the second number: '))
print(tuple(range(number2, number + 1)))
```

Example output:

```
Enter the first number: 7
Enter the second number: -7
(-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: You could format the output to use parentheses with `print(f'({', '.join(list(range(number2, number1 + 1)))})')`

Comment: @VitorFalcão Why not `print(tuple(range(number2, number + 1)))` then?

Comment: @U9-Forward fair enough, I commented before seeing you edit to print with tuple :)

Comment: @Issy if his answer was useful please mark it as the right answer

Comment: @VitorFalcão Yeah, but `tuple` is better as it remains a `tuple` object

Answer (score 0):

Define it as a function. It gives additional functionality to enable the user to also control the step size between the two input numbers.

```
import numpy 

start = input('Enter start number:')
stop = input('Enter stop number:')
step = input('Enter required between two numbers:') 

def list_of_num(start, stop, step):           
    return numpy.arange(int(start), int(stop), int(step))

print(list_of_num(start, stop, step))
```

Comment: overhead, no need for numpy, just use range